# China's victory over Japan was a poisoned chalice

Tags: grammar

I saw this on a newspaper: " For the victory brought in its wake the communist plague.". Is the middle part of the second sentence, "brought in its wake the", correct? I guess it should be "brought its wake in the".

Comment: Why would you guess that? What's wrong with the printed version?

Comment: I didn't know that "in its wake" is an adverbial phase. I get it now, thanks to Janus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guess incorrectly.

“In its wake” belongs together: *its wake* is the object of the preposition *in* (‘its’ referring here back to ‘victory’), and the whole thing is an adverbial phrase. *The communist plague* is the object of the verb.

The phrase switches the default order `Subject – Verb – Object – Adverbial` to a slightly different construction `Subject – Verb – Adverbial – Object` that is possible in some cases, particularly when the `Adverbial` phrase (as here) is a prepositional phrase that is closely associated with the verb.

Undoing this switch, you get:

> China’s victory over Japan was a poisoned chalice, for the victory brought the communist plague in its wake.

Comment: The metaphor is that the thing 'brought in its wake' is an inevitable consequence, just like flotsam 'slipstreams' behind a large ship.